# Inkscape: how to display the buttons name

Tags: inkscape

I'm new to Inkscape so I'm learning the basics.

The buttons name or function doesn't display when I put my cursor over it, like it normally happens (here in Krita). It would greatly help a beginner like me (Window 10 system).

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It does work in Inkscape 1.0. and 0.92.3 (in Windows 10). I just checked.  What version are you using?  Maybe consider an update to a more recent version. Another possibility is a conflict with other software meaning that Inkscape is losing focus for some reason. Do you have any screen recording software installed? Perhaps try exiting it.  Note that it's really hard to answer questions like this without access to your computer system and setup, which is why we usually discourage tech support questions here on GDSE.

Comment: hello, actually it's the latest version, I've just installed it yesterday, ok, I'll check that, thanks

Comment: actually it works fine with the previous version, so I'll begin with this one, thanks again  ;)

Comment: Inkscape 1.0 does have some issues/bugs as it's still quite new, although I'm unable to reproduce this particular problem.  Do you know it's possible to have both versions in Windows?  If you download the 7zip archive for version 1.0, you can just extract it to a folder, using 7-zip, and then you can use it by opening the Inkscape.exe or by creating a shortcut to the exe.

Comment: yes I can work with the previous version, that's what I'll do to begin, then I'll be able to work with the new one  ;)

Comment: If you suspect this could be a bug, please report it to the Inkscape issue tracker, so everyone can benefit from an eventual resolution: https://inkscape.org/report .